# Boolean.valueOf(String) and BooleanUtils.toBoolean(String) in java?

Tags: java, boolean

I have an issue different between `Boolean.valueOf(String)`  and `BooleanUtils.toBoolean(String)`
 .

I use my application just like code `BooleanUtils.toBoolean(defaultInfoRow.getFolderType())` instead `Boolean.valueOf(defaultInfoRow.getFolderType())` both are working fine .

I have some question

1.Which one performance wise better ?

2.which one faster ?

3.in which case prefer  `Boolean.valueOf(String)` ?

Thanks

Comment: According to the Apache doc, theirs is 4x faster than the JDK one.

Comment: The choice between these methods has **NOTHING** to do with performance, because they do different things. Consult the documentation (or the answers below) for more info...

Comment: @Radiodef - _4x faster than JDK 1.4_ **AND**  _with different output..._

Comment: @jahroy I agree it doesn't matter but the doc does claim it's faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the one whose API makes the most sense for your application. `Boolean.valueOf(String)` returns `true` exactly when the argument is the string `"true"`. `BooleanUtils` will treat [several common "true" values](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html#toBoolean%28java.lang.String%29) as `true`. The performance issue is so small as to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

You can ignore performance

[`BooleanUtils`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/BooleanUtils.java#BooleanUtils.toBoolean%28java.lang.String%29) takes care of cases like `On`, `True`, `Yes`, `Boolean.valueOf()` doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Each method behaves differently.

Therefore performance is irrelevant.

You should choose based on the desired behavior:

Use [`Boolean.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) when you **only** want to return *true* for input that equals "*true*" (case insensitive).

Use [`BooleanUtils.toBoolean()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/BooleanUtils.html#toBoolean%28java.lang.String%29) when you want other input to return true (such as "*on*" or "*yes*").

When you have a question about a method, always consult the documentation:

- [`Boolean.valueOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29)
- [`BooleanUtils.toBoolean(String)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/BooleanUtils.html#toBoolean%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't make a choice for either on performance considerations. However, if I have restrictions on using external 3rd part library (e.g. Apache commons lib) I would stick with standard JDK `Boolean.valueOf(String)` though I loose some flexibility on what could be the possible values of `String` input- see earlier answers.

EDIT- this try to answer point #3 in OP's question

Answer (score 1):

[Apache commons documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html#toBoolean-java.lang.String-) says method `BooleanUtils` `public static boolean toBoolean(String str)` performs 4 times faster (JDK1.4) than Boolean.valueOf(String).
Not sure if that is still the case.

Also `BooleanUtils` `public static boolean toBoolean(String str)` supports various options.

```
   BooleanUtils.toBoolean(null)    = false
   BooleanUtils.toBoolean("true")  = true
   BooleanUtils.toBoolean("TRUE")  = true
   BooleanUtils.toBoolean("tRUe")  = true
   BooleanUtils.toBoolean("on")    = true
   BooleanUtils.toBoolean("yes")   = true
   BooleanUtils.toBoolean("false") = false
   BooleanUtils.toBoolean("x gti") = false
   BooleanUtils.toBoolean("y") = true
   BooleanUtils.toBoolean("n") = false
   BooleanUtils.toBoolean("t") = true
   BooleanUtils.toBoolean("f") = false
```

If your project doesn't use Apache commons library already, then it is not worth adding dependency.